# How can I export a variable after value changed from other file in react native?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to export a variable to other file, but what I get in other file is the pre-defined value. How can I get the changed value? Here is my code.

AuthUser.js

```
let phoneNumber = null;
let username = null;
export async function getLoggedinUser() {
    await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() //function provided by AWS to get logged in user data
        .then((data) => {
            phoneNumber = data.attributes.phone_number;
            username = data.attributes.preferred_username;
            console.log('currentAuthenticatedUser() success' + phoneNumber);//output sucess with user phone number
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            phoneNumber = false;
            username = false;
            console.log('currentAuthenticatedUser():' + err);
        });
}
export default {
    phoneNumber,
    username,
};
```

LoginPage.js

```
import { getLoggedinUser } from '../../config/AuthUser';
import AuthUser from '../../config/AuthUser';
...
    async function AuthUserSession() {
        try {
            await getLoggedinUser();
            navigation.navigate('Home');
            console.log('AuthUserSession:' + AuthUser.phoneNumber);//output null(undefined)
        } catch (e) {}
    }
...
```

What I am trying to achieve is to save logged in user data right after user log in. Every page need the data and I do not want to access to AWS Cognito everytime I open a new page. Actually I am not sure will that cost me. May someone familiar with AWS can give me some suggestion on this? Are there any other better solution to handle this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change getLoggedinUser return value to a function, let'say getUserInfo(). after await, call this function to get your information.
You should defind this function in AuthUser.js and return it when data is ready.